# How to Integrate multi-step contact form into flipbox using wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, css, contact-form, elementor

I have a WordPress website using ElementorPro. I would like to integrate a form similar to this one

https://www.fluenthome.com/build/

The form seems to be enclosed in flip-box and on-click next, with flip animation, it goes to the next step and at the end, it gets user's info and send an email.

I google many times and read a lot of forums and questions but couldn't get the way I do that. I'm not a back-end developer so I'm looking forward to some kind of plugin or way that can help me to achieve the desired form.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't be able to achieve something similar with Elementor's Form widget and the Flipbox widget. The closest thing would be to try to implement a multistep form which can be achieved with plugins like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-step-form/

Otherwise, to get what you're looking for you would have to hire a developer to develop it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks @Cesar. I have already tried your suggested plugin. I need the form to behave exactly like in reference site. That's actual issue.